# JavaScript - Adding 2 integers simply doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, math, random, integer, nan

When I try to add two integers together, the integer just stays at what it originally was. It's difficult to explain, so here's my code:

```
var levelRewardsID = parseInt(resultData[0].levelRewardsHighestID)
var levelRewardsIDIncrease = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1
var newLevelRewardsID = levelRewardsID+levelRewardsIDIncrease
console.log(levelRewardsID)
console.log(levelRewardsIDIncrease)
console.log(newLevelRewardsID)
if (!isNaN(levelRewardsID)) {
  console.log("not NAN")
}
if (!isNaN(levelRewardsIDIncrease)) {
  console.log("not NAN 2")
}
if (!isNaN(newLevelRewardsID)) {
   console.log("not NAN 3")
}
```

Console:

```
89819672607051330000
6
89819672607051330000
not NAN
not NAN 2
not NAN 3
```

So as you can see, everything is an integer. So that can't be the issue. Yet when I try to do `var newLevelRewardsID = levelRewardsID+levelRewardsIDIncrease`, the output is the same as `levelRewardsID`... I'm not sure what I did wrong but if anyone knows, do let me know. Thanks!

Note: I'm using Node.JS version 9.1.0 (latest as of posting this) if that helps

Comment: Is `resultData[0].levelRewardsHighestID` `0`?

Comment: @guest271314 nope it's the first log

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's `colors.blue`?

Comment: @aaron just makes the logs have a color, its a library im using called `colors` for node.JS/NPM

Comment: it is not an integer. Integer limit seems to be this 
9007199254740991 your is bigger. try to investigate how to treat it type refernced with different type

Comment: Post a clear and *minimal* example that someone can reproduce easily. We don't know what data your `resultData` Array holds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you reach the javascript number limit which seems to be 9007199254740992 and 89819672607051330000 > 9007199254740992.

See [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: sure enough, lowering the number to 10 digits fixed it! thanks so much for the response :)